# Finding all the rows with 2 conditions using SQL (separate tables)

Tags: sql

I'm having some problems with plain old SQL queries (drawback of using ORMs most of the time :)).

I'm having 2 tables, `PRODUCTS` and `RULES`. In table `RULES` I have defined rules for products. What I want is to write a query to get all products which have defined rules.

Rules are defined by 2 ways:

1. You can specify `RULE` for only one product (`ProductID` have value, `SectorID` is NULL)
2. You can specify `RULE` for more that one product using `SectorID` (`ProductID` is NULL)

Result need to have all products which have rule (`product.ID - rule.ProductID`) but also all products that are defined in sectors which are in rules table (`product.SectorID - rule.SectorID`).

Also, the result can't have duplicate products (products which are defined by `productId` in `RULES` or by `SectorID`)

Example:

**PRODUCTS**

```
ID  SectorID
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   3
6   3
```

**RULES**

```
ID ProductID SectorID
1  1         NULL
4  NULL      1
5  6         NULL
```

**Expected result**

```
PRODUCTS with IDs : 1, 2, 3, 6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of, but not necessarily the quickest.

```
SELECT * FROM products AS p WHERE
       EXISTS (SELECT * FROM rules AS r WHERE p.ID = r.ProductID OR p.SectorID = r.SectorID)
```

Comment: This *will* probably be the quickest (given relevant indexes). Splitting the OR into two separate EXISTS legs could improve things: `WHERE EXISTS ( ... where p.ID = r.ProductID ) OR EXISTS ( ... WHERE p.SectorID = r.SectorID)`

Comment: @wildplasser As far as I can tell, [the query is rewritten as a join anyway](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7c91c/2) with the same plan as the join below.

Answer (score 3):

To get the complete product rows for the matching products, it's a simple `JOIN`. The `DISTINCT` is required since a product may match both a product rule and a sector rule and you only want it listed once.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* 
FROM products p
JOIN rules r
  ON p.ID       = r.ProductID
  OR p.SectorID = r.SectorID
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a734/2).

Answer (score 2):

Perform both queries and combine the results:

```
SELECT ProductID FROM Rules
WHERE ProductID IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT p.ID FROM Product p 
INNER JOIN Rules r ON p.SectorID = r.SectorID
```

The UNION will filter out duplicate IDs. Assuming your example is simplified, you can use this as a subquery to get a list of all products with rules, and use that to join against other tables to return the required data.

An alternative approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID FROM Product p 
INNER JOIN Rules r 
ON p.ID = r.ProductID OR p.SectorID = r.SectorID
```

These may or may not generate different execution plans. You should check, and choose the faster one.

Comment: in your first query the join to the product table is not needed. Just return `r.productID`. Saving a join is always a good thing ;-)

Comment: and the alternate will get duplicates

Answer (score 1):

```
select  distinct
        ProductID
from    rules
where   ProductID is not null
union
select  distinct
        p.id
from    PRODUCTS p
inner join
        RULES r
on      r.sectorid = p.sectorid
```

here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/013a7/2)

Comment: The use of distinct is unnecessary. The second half of the union won't return any duplicates. The first might, but the union will filter them out, even if the duplicate values don't appear in the second half.

Comment: Good point. 

Also, I think Joachim's answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id 
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN Rules r1 ON p.id = r1.productID
LEFT JOIN Rules r2 ON p.SectorID = r2.SectorID
WHERE r1.id IS NOT NULL OR r2.SectorID IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY p.id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/612ae/5)